# GAN code value error from different number of tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I tried to generate a new and bigger dataset using an existing dataset with a GAN model. But I got a value error due to the difference in number of tensors in the sequential layers:

```
ValueError: Layer "sequential_57" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(9, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(9, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel("Initial_pop.xlsx")
data.head()

## Creating a Generator Model
generator = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(10,)),
  tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128),
  tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation="sigmoid")
])

## Creating a Discriminator Model
discriminator = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(3,)),
  tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128),
  tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

discriminator.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy")
generator.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")

epochs = 100
for epoch in range(epochs):
  # Trainning the dis model
  real_data = data[["apogee", "perigee", "inclination"]].values
  fake_data = generator.predict(data[["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", 
"x9", "x10"]].values)
  discriminator_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch([real_data, fake_data], [tf.ones(len(real_data)), tf.zeros(len(fake_data))])

  # Trainning the gen model
  noise = tf.random.normal(shape=(len(data), 11))
  fake_data = generator.predict(noise)
  generator_loss = generator.train_on_batch(noise, fake_data)

  # Print the losses
  print("Epoch {}: discriminator loss = {}, generator loss = {}".format(epoch + 1, discriminator_loss, generator_loss))

# Save the generator
generator.save("generator.h5")

# Generate new data
noise = tf.random.normal(shape=(1000, 11))
new_data = generator.predict(noise)

# Save the new data to a CSV file
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=["apogee", "perigee", "inclination"])
new_df.to_csv("new_data.csv", index=False
```